# What is the difference between "data" versus "=" in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran and I'd like to understand the differences between these two statements:

```
logical :: TF
TF = .true.
```

and:

```
logical :: TF
data TF/.true./
```

Please keep the response in more simple to words, I've recently moved from Python to this compiled language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosely, a DATA statement performs explicit initialization of a variable.  An assignment statement gives a variable a value.

These are very different things.  You can consider the DATA statement version of this question like

```
logical, save:: TF=.TRUE.
```

and see many questions/complaints about how this behaves unexpectedly.

In general, it's worth noting that DATA statement and the "declaration with SAVE" (actually an initialization on declaration) are also (subtly) different. As a beginner, perhaps pretend these initializations don't exist and stick to assignment.

Comment: I see, so the data statment has the same effect as using a declaration ( "=" ) and a "save" statement?

Comment: The effect isn't precisely the same. In the case of the question, yes it is, but it many other cases, no it isn't.

Comment: A DATA statement supplies a one-time initialization of a variable at program start. It isn't the same as assignment as that happens each time the assignment is executed. In newer Fortran standards one can add an initialization on the variable declaration instead of using DATA. Both forms imply the SAVE attribute, which makes a variable retain its value across procedure invocations.