# How to rewrite code with SAVE and ENTRY statements for OpenMP usage?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, refactoring, openmp, fortran77

I am rewriting for OpenMP usage a large Fortran-77 program and one of the files contains a subroutine in which important variables marked as SAVE are initialized the first time the main program is called, and then they are used when called in the same subroutine via ENTRY points.
I decided to replace this file with a long subroutine with a module containing several subroutines (the functionality of which was called through the ENTRY points), and before the CONTAINS statement, list those important variables that are marked SAVE in the source program so that they are available in all modules subroutines calls.

However, I can't get the functionality to work. How else can I rewrite SAVE-ENTRY constructions in subroutine?
My minimal main program example:

```fortran
c     elementary program to add two numbers, using 
c     a module containing important variables and 
c     two addition functions, one for the case where 
c     one number is zero and the second for the case
c     of non-zero terms

      PROGRAM sum0
      USE SUMM
      INTEGER i,j
      WRITE (6,*) 'Enter two numbers: '
      READ (5,*) i,j

      IF (i .EQ. 0) THEN
          CALL sum1(j)
      ELSE IF (j .EQ. 0) THEN
          CALL sum1(i)
      ELSE
          CALL sum2(i,j)
      ENDIF

      END PROGRAM sum0
```

And module:

```fortran
      MODULE SUMM
            IMPLICIT NONE
c           "important" variables that had the status SAVE: 
            REAL B(2,2), K
c           initialization via DATA works similarly to SAVE (I think so): 
            DATA B/1.0,-3.7,4.3,0.0/, K/33.0/

        CONTAINS
            SUBROUTINE sum2(i1,j1)
                INTEGER i1,j1
                i1 = i1 + j1
                WRITE (6,*) 'The first element of B is', B(1,1), '.'
                WRITE (6,*) 'The K is', K, '.'
                WRITE (6,*) 'The sum of the numbers is', i1, '.'
            END SUBROUTINE sum2

            SUBROUTINE sum1(i1)
                INTEGER i1
                WRITE (6,*) 'The first element of B is', B(1,1), '.'
                WRITE (6,*) 'The K is', K, '.'
                WRITE (6,*) 'The sum of the numbers is', i1, '.'
            END SUBROUTINE sum1
      END MODULE SUMM
```

Original file:

```fortran
      SUBROUTINE SUMM
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
      REAL B(2,2), K
      DATA B/1.0,-3.7,4.3,0.0/
      SAVE
      K = 33.0
      
      RETURN

      ENTRY sum2(i,j)
      i = i + j
      WRITE (6,*) 'The first element of B is', B(1,1), '.'
      WRITE (6,*) 'The K is', K, '.'
      WRITE (6,*) 'The sum of the numbers is', i, '.'
      RETURN

      ENTRY sum1(i)
      WRITE (6,*) 'The first element of B is', B(1,1), '.'
      WRITE (6,*) 'The K is', K, '.'
      WRITE (6,*) 'The sum of the numbers is', i, '.'
      RETURN

      END
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: In what way can't you "get the functionality to work"? What appears to go wrong?

Comment: Oh, why isn't? When I added my module then the code immediately stopped giving correct values in a very remote place, I decided to ask a question while I try to debug somehow. Maybe there is a general approach to refactoring in such a case that I don't know

Comment: There is a big difference between the original and your module: in the module `k` has explicit initialization whereas the original does not. In the original, absent a call to `summ` `k` remains undefined. It would be helpful to see a [mre] (and output) with both forms.

Comment: In 5 line of original file `k` is initialized with the real number `33.0`. Console output in original case:
```Enter two numbers: ```
```0 2```
 ```The first element of B is   1.000000     .```
 ```The K is   33.00000     .```
 ```The sum of the numbers is           2 .```

Comment: In module-case console output is:

```Enter two numbers: 
2 2
 The first element of B is   1.00000000     .
 The K is   33.0000000     .
 The sum of the numbers is           4 .
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253202/discussion-between-djnz-and-francescalus).

Comment: Line 5 of the original does not _initialize_ `k` (in the sense of providing explicit initialization). It is an assignment statement which defines `k` if and only if it is executed. This is in contrast to the initialization of `B` through a DATA statement.

Comment: However, the effect is exactly the same as SAVE...
(I made a mistake only in the order of the initialization expressions for K and SAVE in the original file, I have already corrected (thanks for your attention))

Comment: No it isn't. A SAVE statement means the value is retained between invocations. It doesn't give `k` a value. Explicit initialization implies the SAVE attribute, but `k` is not given an initial value, regardless of SAVE.

Comment: [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73325634/3157076) goes in to detail of the difference between explicit initialization and assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I've just rebuilt the project with the original file with different compilers, and this is what I found out:
1. Ifort makes it so that the value `K=33.0` is saved on calls to ENTRY even without SAVE statement
2. Gfortran without SAVE displays `K` is `0.0`, and with SAVE statement shows that `K` is `33.0`

Comment: What @francescalus is trying to tell you is that you need a third subroutine in your module and it must be called before either `sum2` or `sum1`.  You need `subroutine summ; k = 33.0; end subroutine summ`.  This does the initialization of `k` and will do a re-initialization if called a second time.  In the module remove the `k/33./` from the `data` statement and simple declare `k`.  It automatically has the `save` attribute because it is a module variable.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you have `implicit none` in the original code.  Neither `i` nor `j` is declared.  There is no way that code compiled with gfortran.

Comment: Very thanks, @steve! I fixed the `implicit none` bug (copy-paste! sorry!). Thanks a lot for the explanation: everything worked.

Comment: you're welcomed.  happy hacking.